# Problema al compilar c++ con cygwin

Tags: c++

al compilar un programa en c++ con cygwin me sale el siguiente error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): referencia a `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' sin definir
/cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): reubicación truncada para ajustar: R_X86_64_PC32 contra el símbolo `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' sin definir
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): referencia a `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))' sin definir
/cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): reubicación truncada para ajustar: R_X86_64_PC32 contra el símbolo `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))' sin definir
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5f): referencia a `std::ios_base::Init::Init()' sin definir
/cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5f): reubicación truncada para ajustar: R_X86_64_PC32 contra el símbolo `std::ios_base::Init::Init()' sin definir
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev[.refptr._ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev]+0x0): referencia a `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' sin definir
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_[.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_]+0x0): referencia a `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)' sin definir
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/Sergio/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFSZ5F5.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): referencia a `std::cout' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
```

Estoy probando con main.cpp bastante sencillo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "\nHello World\n " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Adjunto una foto para que se vea mejor, uso el comando `gcc -o prueba main.cpp` dentro del directorio del proyecto.

[image: Problema al compilar con cygwin]

Comment: Prueba compilarlo con `g++` en lugar de `gcc`

Comment: No es un error de compilación, sino, un error de vinculación. El enlazador no está encontrando la biblioteca estándar de C++, por lo que daría todo esos errores. La solución es indicar explicitamente al linker el nombre de la biblioteca: `gcc main.cpp -o main -lstdc++`